# Could not find any font sans error in CIS RedHat 7 Enterprise

Tags: linux, fonts, centos, redhat

I'm trying to run a program and I got following errors in the new CIS RedHat Enterprise but not the old version of CIS RedHat Ent.

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "localhost:0.0".
[0814/202432:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(343)] glxQueryVersion failed
[0814/202432:ERROR:gl_surface_x11.cc(56)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[0814/202432:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(227)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0814/202435:FATAL:platform_font_linux.cc(59)] Check failed: typeface. Could not find any font: 0x7ffcea8b2b20, sans
Aborted
```

it complained because it can't find the font sans. Does any one has any idea what seem to be wrong and how to resolve it? Maybe I need to install default set of fonts on machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found my own answer:

```
yum install 'gnu-free-sans-fonts'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is testing if the "Sans" font exists on-system.
"Sans" is not a real font but an alias to the highest-priority font installed (like css generic fonts)

Serif fonts do not work well on low resolution screens, so if there is a font installed at all it will usually be sans-serif